# Convergence of Markov process as some rates tend to infinity

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stationary-processes

Take the simple two state Markov process characterized by transitions 
$$
\begin{aligned}
0\rightarrow1 & \quad \text{ at rate }  \quad \alpha\lambda \\
1\rightarrow0 & \quad \text{ at rate }  \quad \alpha.
\end{aligned}
$$

If we let $\alpha$ go to infinity, then we effectively have a stationary process. No matter what the initial distribution, the process at any future time has distribution $\pi.$ Is that correct? I know that $\pi=(\pi_0,\pi_1)=\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda},\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)$ irrespective of $\alpha.$

What if we introduce another state $2$ with transitions 
$$
\begin{aligned}
0\rightarrow2 & \quad \text{ at rate }  \quad \gamma_{02} \\
1\rightarrow2 & \quad \text{ at rate }  \quad \gamma_{12} \\
2\rightarrow1 & \quad \text{ at rate }  \quad \beta \\
2\rightarrow0 & \quad \text{ at rate }  \quad \delta.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now call this $3$ state process $X_\alpha.$

Now what happens as we let $\alpha\rightarrow\infty?$ Presumably $X_\alpha\overset{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} X$ where $X$ is the process which can be characterized with what follows.

We can think of $X$ as having only two states: $\{0,1\}$ and $2.$

The transitions of $X$ are 
$$\{0,1\}\rightarrow2 \quad \text{ at rate } \quad \gamma_{02} \pi_0+\gamma_{12} \pi_1$$ 
where $\pi_i$ is as described above, and 
$$2\rightarrow\{0,1\} \quad \text{ at rate } \quad \delta+\beta.$$

**Question:** Is it ok to think of $X$ in this way (as a two-state process)? When $X$ is not in state $2$, we know its distribution is $\pi$, yes?

What would be the best way to formalize the idea of $X_\alpha\overset{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} X?$ I.e. what mode of convergence should be used?

Comment: This phenomenon of "aggregating" states is a major part of "Freidlin-Wentzell theory". In this first step, grouping $0$ and $1$ together, you have identified the *first order cycles* in the hierarchy of Freidlin cycles. You can find a great deal of detail on this subject (although mostly focused on the context of continuous space) in the book *Random perturbations of dynamical systems*.

Comment: By the way, you should keep in mind that usually we think about this situation in a sense inverted from what you have described here. Usually some or all of the transition rates of the process are going to *zero*. Then a different level of the Freidlin cycle hierarchy is appropriate depending on what time scale you are looking at.

Comment: One major example that is motivated by situations in physics is where you have $n$ states with "minimum energies" $V_i \geq 0$ and "saddle energies" $V_{ij}=V_{ji} \geq 0$. Here the saddle energies can be $+\infty$ but the minimum energies cannot. The transition rate from $i$ to $j$ here is proportional to or at least logarithmically equivalent to $e^{-\beta(V_{ij}-V_i)}$ where $\beta>0$ is a large parameter.

Comment: Now generically, for any state $i$, there is a state most asymptotically accessible from $i$. Following such paths, you will eventually find a loop (though it may not come back to $i$). These loops, and any isolated states not in any loop, are the first order Freidlin cycles. You obtain higher order cycles by defining a new process on the macrostates (as you did) and repeating the procedure.

Comment: @Ian, thanks for the info. I will do some reading! I could also rescale time by $1/\alpha$ as still let $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$, and it seems like that would result in $2$ being an absorbing state and otherwise dynamics equivalent to the first process on $0$ and $1$ (absent $\alpha$). It's just two different perspectives for the same process, as far as $\{0,1\}$ are concerned, a $2$ lives for infinitely long. As far as $2$ is concerned, the $0$ and $1$ flip back and forth infinitely fast. I'm really curious on how to formalize this. I'm pretty sure I've seen it before in papers.

Comment: Part of what I was saying is that it's not actually "infinitely long". It is "much longer than the time scale of some other subprocess(es)". Thinking of it as "infinitely long" does not permit us to distinguish between *different* "infinitely long" time periods. For instance you can have the scenario I described with $V_1=V_3=0,V_2=1,V_{12}=2,V_{23}=3,V_{31}=10$. Then $1$ tends to go to $2$, $2$ tends to go back to $1$, and eventually, the system escapes $\{ 1,2 \}$.

Comment: But the system will escape *via 2*, not via $1$, because the barrier to reach $3$ from $1$ is $10$ while the barrier to reach $3$ from $2$ is $2$. This is true even after you account for the fact that the system spends most of its time at $1$ when it is in $\{ 1,2 \}$. So forgetting about the microstates entirely is a mistake, because there is "microscale" information that can be inferred at even higher levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: If $S_\alpha(t)$ is the semigroup for $X_\alpha$, then we can show that for any initial distribution $\mu$ and any fixed $t$ we have $\mu S_\alpha(t)\rightarrow\pi$ weakly as $\alpha\rightarrow\infty.$ Does that make sense? It's a fairly straightforward calculation I think. Does it then make sense to say $X_\alpha$ converges to $X?$ (weakly? in measure? in distribution?)

Comment: As I recall these results go through at the level of convergence in probability. But they only do that when you zoom in on the proper time scale.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? Shouldn't $P(X_\alpha(t)=0, X(t)=1)$ be close to $\pi_0\pi_1$ for $\alpha$ large? I don't see a nice way to couple the processes together, so they can be treated as independent, yes? It seems like no matter how large $\alpha$ is, for whatever interval of time $X_\alpha$ remains at $0$, we have $X=1$ for proportion $\pi_1$ of that interval, so $P(|X_\alpha(t)-X(t)|=1)\geq A>0$ for any fixed $t>0$ and a suitably chosen $A.$

Comment: You are thinking of $t$ as fixed. Since you are also sending $\alpha \to \infty$, that amounts to enforcing a time scale, where there is time available for $O(\alpha)$ transitions involving the two $\alpha$ processes and $O(1)$ transitions involving the other four processes. *On that time scale*, $X_\alpha$ converges to $X$ in an appropriate sense (not quite "in probability" because the two processes take on different values, but similar to that).

Comment: On a *shorter* time scale, say times of $O(1/\alpha)$, $X_\alpha$ does *not* converge to $X$; on these time scales, $0$ and $1$ are still equilibrating with each other and $2$ is essentially not relevant.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying about the different timescales. It seems like we have to choose a fixed time -scale, -interval, or -point in order to ask the question about convergence in $\alpha$ though. Maybe convergence in distribution at each fixed $t$ is the best I can get here. Convergence in probability of $X_\alpha$ to $X$ seems to require a way to measure the distance between the processes, and I don't see a way to do that in such a way that convergence occurs.

Comment: You do have $P(X_\alpha(t) \in \{ 0,1 \}) \to P(X(t) \in \{ 0,1 \})$ and $P(X_\alpha(t) = 2) \to P(X(t)=2)$, for each fixed $t$. What you don't have is of course $P(X_\alpha(t)=0) \to P(X(t)=0)$ because the latter expression makes no sense.

Comment: I agree with the first statement. So is it wrong to say that $P(X(t)=0)=\pi_0$ for each fixed $t$ or is it wrong to say that $P(X_\alpha(t)=0)\overset{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\longrightarrow\pi_0$ for each fixed $t?$ I have that $P(X_\alpha(t)=i)=P(X_1(\alpha t)=i)$. As $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$, $P(X_1(\alpha t)=i)\rightarrow\pi_i.$ Does that make sense?

Comment: $P(X(t)=0)$ makes no sense, because $X$ does not distinguish between $0$ and $1$. $P(X_\alpha(t)=0) \to \pi_0$ (where $\pi_0$ is defined as in your question) is also not necessarily true because that neglects the possibility that it is $2$. $P(X_\alpha(t)=0 \mid X_\alpha(t) \in \{ 0,1 \}) \to \pi_0$ is correct.

Comment: Ok, I see! Dropping $t$ we have $P(X=0|X\neq2)=\pi_0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty} P(X_\alpha=i|X_\alpha\neq2)=\pi_i$ for $i=0,1.$ But overall, the question of convergence is ill-conceived unless we lump together $\{0,1\}$. I think that essentially solves my questions. I think I now see that this is what you were getting at the entire discussion. So as long as I restrict myself to the space of functions satisfying $f(0)=f(1)$, I will get (weak) convergence in distribution.